# Remove double or more lines empty and keep a single line empty

Tags: python

I have a string with multiple empty lines, I want to remove them but keep **one** line break, for example:

```
Line one






Line two
Line three


Line Four

Line Five
```

What I want to achieve is this result

```
Line one

Line two
Line three

Line Four

Line Five
```

What is the approach should I use?

Comment: "*What is the approach should I use?*" Write code to find three or more consecutive line breaks and replace them all with two consecutive line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and `re.sub` in particular:

```
>>> s = """Line one






Line two
Line three


Line Four

Line Five"""

>>> clean = re.sub(r"\n\n+", "\n\n", s)
>>> print(clean)
Line one

Line two
Line three

Line Four

Line Five
```